# Only whole numbers and specific text in excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to enter only whole numbers and specific texts (Eg: A,B,C alone) in a column. How can i do this?

Comment: with data validation

Comment: Is **zero** valid??

Comment: Are negative whole numbers valid??

Comment: Are both upper case and lower case **A**, **B**, **C** ??

Comment: only 0,positive numbers,A,B,C

Comment: both upper case and lower case A,B,C is acceptable

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to limit column entries either with text or with numbers, but not the combination of both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data validation with this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),AND(A1=INT(A1),A1>=0),OR(EXACT(A1,"A"),EXACT(A1,"B"),EXACT(A1,"C")))
```

Comment: Is is possible to provide the same option in a List?